# Angular re-sizing dynamic object when a menu is opened

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, dom, scrollbar

I am working a angularjs project with a dynamic object(pdf) and a collapsible item within an iframe.  Since I am in an iframe I am restricted to the width and height of the iframe.  I currently have an issue when a collapsible is opened it creates a double scroll bar.  When the collapsible menu opens it creates a second scroll bar :-(.  I would like to re-size the dynamic object without reloading the document to get rid of the second scroll bar.

I have tried when the collapsible is pushed to toggle and select document by ID and re-size the height, but that doesn't seem to work.

Plunker Example [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/I3RCT9xjVT9f371YoGvH?p=preview)

Here is what bothers me:
[image]

### JS

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
.controller('CollapseController', function($scope,$sce,$document){$scope.collapsed = true;
$scope.name = 'World';
$scope.documentSrc = "http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf";


$scope.frameSrc = $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.documentSrc);
$scope.frameCode = $sce.trustAsHtml('<object data="http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object>');
$scope.display = false;

$scope.toggleCollapsed = function(){
  var temp = '';
  $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed;
  if($scope.collapsed){
    $document.find('#currentDocument').height = 300;
  }else{
    $document.find('#currentDocument').height = 200;
  }
}

$scope.changeDoc = function(){
  $scope.documentSrc = 'https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Web_Hosting_Best_Practices.pdf';
};
$scope.changeDocAgain = function (){
  $scope.documentSrc = 'http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf';
};

})
.directive('embedSrc', function () {
return {
  restrict: 'A',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.$watch(
      function() {
        return attrs.embedSrc;
      },
      function() {
        element.attr('src', attrs.embedSrc);
      }
    );
  }
};
})
.directive('dynamicObject', function($parse) {
  return {
  restrict: 'E',
  link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(function() {
        return $parse(attrs.data)(scope);
      }, function(newValue) {
        element.html('<object data="' + newValue + '" type="application/pdf" class="document_size" id="currentDocument"></object>');
      });
   }
   };
});;
```

### HTML/CSS

```
<style>
.menuBar{
  background :gray;
}

.document_size{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
.ExampleIFRAME{
  height: 600px;
  overflow-y:auto;
}
</style>
<body ng-controller="CollapseController">
  <div class="ExampleIFRAME">
    <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleCollapsed()">Toggle</button>
    <button ng-click="changeDoc()">Change Doc</button>
    <button ng-click="changeDocAgain()">Change Again Doc</button>

    <br/><br/>
    <div collapse="collapsed">
      <div class="menuBar">
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <dynamic-object data="documentSrc"></dynamic-object>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks fine on chrome...

Comment: @malix : I added a picture of what is wrong.  And that picture is a screen shot from google chrome.

Comment: Ah! It's on Windows?

Comment: it's scroll bars within a browser.

Comment: I understand that... But your Chrome is running in Windows, Linux, OSX?

Comment: Both IE and Chrome are running on a windows 7 64 bit machine